# Every time I run exe the new file getting created?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

Hi I have converted my python code to exe using pyinstaller,
I'm converting my python code to single file using the below .spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['obiee_pbi_connector\\migration.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Automation projects\\bimigration_demo_for_ms\\back_end_python'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('logging.ini','../.'),('pbi','../pbi'),('obiee_repo','../obiee_repo'),('config','../config'),('exe_dependencies/Lib/site-packages/tableauhyperapi','./tableauhyperapi'),('exe_dependencies/Lib/site-packages/tableauhyperapi-0.0.13394.dist-info','tableauhyperapi-0.0.13394.dist-info'),('exe_dependencies/Lib/site-packages/pythonjsonlogger','pythonjsonlogger'),('exe_dependencies/Lib/site-packages/python_json_logger-2.0.2.dist-info','python_json_logger-2.0.2.dist-info')
                    ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='revive',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

when you convert it into only one file the configuration and temporary files that we write/read will be present at the temp folder of current user

Where I'm using add data to create move my sqlite db, configuration files, and two libraries(because it's not getting packaged so I'm doing like this), whenever I run exe all these files getting copied to temp folder, so each time I run my application it's seems to be newly installed one, how can I resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to edit those sqlite.db .... files (and save them) at run-time?

Comment: @gfdsweds hi, I didn't get you could you please more elaborate

Comment: Oh, I guess you can just let the program copy those configuration files you need into some directories like %appdata%, to preserve user configuration settings.

Comment: How those configuration files are used?

Comment: @gfdsweds how can you main updated sqlite db in this scenario

Comment: What is the sqlite.db?